# Use of an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) with event emitters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to do a sanity check on how I've written the following code. The code lists 3 messages from an email account, then downloads and parses each of the message bodies, and saves the result to a Mongo database. Although this is Node.js code I think my question is general to javascript. On my first attempt (code shown below), the same message prints to the console and gets saved to the database 3 times. The intended functionality is for 3 different messages to get saved to the database. I figured the problem had something to do with `messages[x]` not being properly sent into the emitted `"end"` event via the variable `objMessageHeader`, so in the second code example I added an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) as shown. The 3 messages now download correctly to the database, instead of downloading and saving the same message 3 times to the database.

**I can't help but think the IIFE solution is hackish.** Is this the right way to do it? Is this an antipattern, and is there a better or different way? If you're not sure how to answer, perhaps you could explain why the first attempt didn't work and the second attempt does.

Note: the `client.createMessageStream(... objMailParser)` line eventually triggers the `objMailParser`'s `"end"` event.

This was my first attempt, which didn't work correctly and saved the same message 3 times to the database:

```
client.listMessages(-3, function(err, messages){ 

    for (var x=0; x <= messages.length-1; x++) { 

        var objMessageHeader = messages[x];

        var objMailParser = new MailParser(); 

        objMailParser.on("end", function(objParsedMessage){
            console.log("["+objMessageHeader.UIDValidity+"."+objMessageHeader.UID+"] Subject: <"+objMessageHeader.title+"> Flags: <"+objMessageHeader.flags+">");
            console.log("---------------------------------------------------------<<<");
            console.log("From:", objParsedMessage.from);
            console.log("Subject:", objParsedMessage.subject);
            console.log("Text body:", objParsedMessage.text);
            console.log(">>>---------------------------------------------------------");

            var objMessage = objMessageHeader;
            objMessage.type = "message";
            objMessage.account = "someemail@yahoo.com";
            objMessage.mailboxPath = strMailboxPath;

            objMessage.parsedMessage = objParsedMessage;

            saveMessageToDBMongo("first100", strMailboxPath, collMessages, objMessage);

        }); // objMailParser.on("end" ...

        client.createMessageStream(objMessageHeader.UID).pipe(objMailParser);

    } // for (var x=0 ...
}); // client.listMessages ...
```

And this is the modified code with an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), which works correctly, saving 3 separate messages to the database:

```
client.listMessages(-3, function(err, messages){ 

    for (var x=0; x <= messages.length-1; x++) { 
        var message_header_super = messages[x];

        //var objMessageHeader = messages[x];

        (function iifeParseMessageBody(objMessageHeader){
            var objMailParser = new MailParser(); 

            objMailParser.on("end", function(objParsedMessage){
                console.log("["+objMessageHeader.UIDValidity+"."+objMessageHeader.UID+"] Subject: <"+objMessageHeader.title+"> Flags: <"+objMessageHeader.flags+">");
                console.log("---------------------------------------------------------<<<");
                console.log("From:", objParsedMessage.from);
                console.log("Subject:", objParsedMessage.subject);
                console.log("Text body:", objParsedMessage.text);
                console.log(">>>---------------------------------------------------------");

                var objMessage = objMessageHeader;
                objMessage.type = "message";
                objMessage.account = "neatcode@yahoo.com";
                objMessage.mailboxPath = strMailboxPath;

                objMessage.parsedMessage = objParsedMessage;

                saveMessageToDBMongo("first100", strMailboxPath, collMessages, objMessage);

            }); // objMailParser.on("end" ...

            client.createMessageStream(objMessageHeader.UID).pipe(objMailParser);
        }.call(this, message_header_super));

    } // for (var x=0 ...
}); // client.listMessages ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one copy of the x variable when inside a loops closure and all of the bindings see the same value. If you are going to use `x` in your binding you will need to break out the loop and use a new scope for each binding (this can be done with an IIFE). Your message is saving 3 times because `x` is always `3`

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vc149s70/

If you look at the `setTimeout()` console log the result is always `test3` however in the `MailParser()` timeout the results are correct.

Using an IIFE is a correct way of solving this as you are simply creating a new scope and passing in `x`. There are a number of other ways to do this but I think in your case the IIFE is fine.